# PHP remove all spaces after specific character

Tags: php

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
What word is on page 9, 4 words from the left on line 15?   account
What word is on page 11, 2 words from the left on line 5?   always
```

Is there a way that I can remove all of the spaces after the "?" so it looks something like this (the space amounts are all different throughout the actual text file):

```
What word is on page 9, 4 words from the left on line 15?account
What word is on page 11, 2 words from the left on line 5?always
```

Comment: learn about the trim functions

Comment: @PHPNooB Trim functions remove character from beginning or end of string, not middle.

Comment: you need a regular expression that matches `?` + spaces and replaces with '?' - `'\?\s+'` is that expression. Use it in `preg_replace`...

Comment: You're abusing the down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
$str = 'What word is on page 9, 4 words from the left on line 15?   account';
echo preg_replace('/\?\s+/', '?', $str);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, it worked perfectly. Both you and @JohnConde were just seconds apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = 'What word is on page 9, 4 words from the left on line 15?   account';
echo preg_replace('/\?\s+/', '?', $input);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Rgu3tb)